# Skipped cin when a string is entered?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I am experimenting on how functions in C++ work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int add(int num, int num2){
    return num + num2;
}

int main(){

    int n1, n2;
    cout << "first\t";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "second\t";
    cin >> n2;

    cout << "----------\nResult\t" << add(n1, n2) << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It works great when I enter two numbers; but when I enter a string, it simply skipped the `cin >> n2` line and return `6959982`.

```
first   test
second  ----------
Result  6959982
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: You should always check the result of input operations. `if (std::cin >> n1)`

Comment: What has that to do with "how functions work"?

Comment: @KerrekSB - That `add` function right there.

Comment: OK, but your question isn't about the `add` function or how it works, is it? You could trim all that fat.

Comment: Start reading from this one on: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/stream-input-failure.html

Comment: TO put it simply: Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @chris - How do you do it with `if`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, It's pretty similar to the link I gave and its `while` solution, the difference being you'd not keep trying until they get it right.

Comment: @chris - I understand from the link you gave that it stopped working is because `cin` went in a "failed state". So what can I do to make it get out of that state?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, Keep reading on through the sections listed after this one to the left for a few sections.

Comment: @chris - Thanks, `cin.clear` and `ignore` are what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just nothing is read. Stream gets the fail bit and ignores all subsequent readings.

```
6959982 is initial value of n2.
```

You should check the result of reading. Example:

```
if(!(cin >> n1)) {
   cout << "input is garbage!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

```
// Ask for a number, and if it is not a number, report invalid input.
while ((std::cout << "Number: ") && !(std::cin >> num)) {
    std::cout << "Invalid Input." << std::endl;
}
```

The funny number is because in C++, integers are by default not 0 (they can be depending on the implementation).  So whenever you declare a number, you should set it to a default:

```
int x = 0;
```

Comment: It's not really that they're by default not 0, but that they're not 0 by default. The first makes it sound like they're always assigned a nonzero value, when in reality, they're uninitialized and trying to access the value results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: In most implementations (if not all), it keeps the value that was left at that address in memory